# Can't convert image to grayscale when using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have a transparent logo that I want to convert to grayscale using OpenCV. I am using the following code

```
def to_grayscale(logo):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(logo, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    canny = cv2.Canny(blur, 50, 150)  # sick
    return canny
```

This is the image variable:

```
brand_logo = Image.open(current_dir + '/logos/' + logo_image, 'r').convert('RGBA')
brand_logo = to_grayscale(brand_logo)
```

And this is the error:

```
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'
```

I tried to use `.convert('L')` from PIL but it makes it 90% transparent gray. Anyway I can fix this issue?

**Update**

```
def to_grayscale(logo):
    OCVim = np.array(logo)
    BGRim = cv2.cvtColor(OCVim, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
    blurry = cv2.GaussianBlur(BGRim, (5, 5), 0)
    canny = cv2.Canny(blurry, 50, 150)
    PILim = Image.fromarray(canny)
    return PILim
```

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing **OpenCV** and **PIL/Pillow** unnecessarily and will confuse yourself. If you open an image with **PIL**, you will get a `PIL Image` which is doubly no use for **OpenCV** because:

- **OpenCV** expects `Numpy arrays`, not `PIL Images`, and
- **OpenCV** uses BGR ordering, not RGB ordering like **PIL** uses.

The same applies when saving images.

There are three possible solutions:

- stick to **PIL**
- stick to **OpenCV**
- convert every time you move between the two packages.

---

To convert from `PIL Image` to **OpenCV**'s `Numpy array`:

```
OCVim = np.array(PILim)
```

To convert from **OpenCV**'s `Numpy array` to `PIL Image`:

```
PILim = Image.fromarray(OCVim)
```

---

To reverse the colour ordering, not necessary with greyscale obviously, either use:

```
BGRim = cv2.cvtColor(RGBim, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
```

or use a negative Numpy stride:

```
BGRim = RGBim[..., ::-1]
```

Comment: Hey man. Check the updated question. I applied your changes and now it just creates a white outline of the logo..

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Do you want to extract the alpha channel? Is the image your actual starting image? What is the expected result? Thank you.

Comment: The logos are not like this. They're colored logos with transparent backgrounds. I want to turn these logos gray and paste them..

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and make sure the words and images match whatever it is you want to do. Thank you.

Comment: How do they not match?

Comment: The question is very clear.  I have logos that I want to convert to grayscale using OpenCV