# Is there an skimage alternative to OpenCV's ArUco library?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scikit-image

I have used OpenCV in the past for a project of mine, and I remember the AruCo library being very useful to specify certain regions, to calibrate the camera, etc.
I am currently working on another project that will get involved with image processing, and I've been working with SciPy in general for data-related tasks. As I will be using SciPy, I've been considering to work with skimage, as it may be more related to the other packages I will use.
Here's the question: I want to use something similar to, if not the same as, the AruCo library for skimage as it will be convenient to work with. Is there such a solution for skimage?

Here's the library in question,
[AruCo library for OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.0/d9/d6a/group__aruco.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging around, I've noticed that OpenCV and skimage are compatible with each other to a great extent. The only issue I've encountered so far is with io.imshow() and cv2.imshow() yielding negative-like colors with respect to each other (in Colab, that is).
If that (and other potential minor issues) could be resolved, it is quite easy to just use AruCo with cv2 and use skimage wherever needed. It could take some work, but it is possible.

Here's a great example from the skimage library *itself*, where the library `cv` is used to capture webcam feeds. So they are actually compatible.
*Note*: This is deprecated, so just consider it as a proof. There may be better solutions to use a webcam feed than this (could just use `cv2` for it)
https://gist.github.com/stefanv/5160329

Comment: Here's what's going on with the colours and how to fix it... https://stackoverflow.com/a/65435569/2836621

Comment: I'd never imagine Pillow being the reason for the weird colors, not that it will be a problem for me but I do appreciate the input!

Comment: It's actually **OpenCV** that's the odd one because it uses BGR. Everyone else uses RGB.